# preg_match_all() not matching all possible occurrences

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all

I have binary pattern "10000101001" and I want to match string having 0 in starting and ending 1. So for above given example there should be 3 possible match 100001, 101, 1001.

Below is the sample code I am trying:

```
function solution() {
    $length = 0;
    $decStr = "10000101001";
    $pattern = "/[1][^1]0*[1]/";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $decStr, $matches);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

This gives output as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100001
            [1] => 1001
        )

)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Positive lookahead

```
/(?=(1[^1]+1))/
```

Read this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: never heard that before, anyway this has resolved the issue!!